# Pleaes help to improve PHP script so I can download larger video files (nearly 500 MB) from my website

Tags: php

When I try to download large size video from my PHP website, download stopped after downloading nearly 18 MB.

---

I am using following script to download video file.

```
@ignore_user_abort();
@set_time_limit(0);
ob_end_clean();

if (!is_file($str_clip_path) or connection_status()!=0) return(FALSE);

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")))." GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".(filesize($str_clip_path)));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$str_download_filename);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

if ($fp = fopen($str_clip_path, 'rb')) 
{
    while(!feof($fp)) 
    {
        print(fread($fp, 1*(1024*1024)));
        flush();
    ob_flush();
    }
    fclose($fp);
    exit();
}
```

---

On my IIS server, following values are set for specific variables.

```
memory_limit        512M
max_execution_time          10800
max_input_time      10800
post_max_size       512M
upload_max_filesize     512M
```

Please help me to make necessary changes in above script so I can download larger video files from website.

Thank you in advance,
KRA

Comment: Why do you need `ob_flush()` after you disabled output buffering? Also try to analyze your PHP error logs.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using PHP for this? Why not just serve the file directly from your web server? Also, if you can run Apache instead of IIS, consider using xsendfile https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: Hello, Jani Hartikainen, can you please explain that how to serve file directly from my web server? Also, I can't use Apache server.

Comment: @KRA You would put the files in a directory which is public, similar to how you put a PHP file there and people can access it. I'm not really familiar enough with IIS to help more, but you can refer to the IIS manual or such

Answer (score 0):

If you using nginx web server you can use [x-accel-redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile)